# Splash Screen in Tkinter/Python gives error

Tags: python, tkinter

The image for a splash screen in Tkinter is splash.png. It is in the same directory as the source code, which is the current directory. However, I'm getting a "TclError: "pyimage38" doesn't exist" which indicates that the Tkinter image reference is lost or not properly handled.

Can anybody find the bug? It looks fine to me....

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

current_directory = os.getcwd()

# Print the current directory
print(current_directory)

def load_splash_image():
    global splash_tk_image
    
    # Load the splash image
    splash_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "splash.png")
    splash_image = Image.open(splash_path)
    splash_tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(splash_image)
    
    # Create a label to display the splash image
    splash_label = ttk.Label(root)
    splash_label.config(image=splash_tk_image)
    splash_label.image = splash_tk_image  # Store the image as an attribute of the label
    
    # Center the splash label on the root window
    splash_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
    
    # Start a timer to hide the splash screen after 3 seconds
    timer = root.after(3000, lambda: splash_label.destroy())

# Create a root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Hide the root window until the splash screen is displayed
root.withdraw()

# Call the function to load the splash image
load_splash_image()

# Show the root window after the splash screen is destroyed
root.deiconify()

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems unlikely you would get that error. `pyimage38` implies the code has created 37 other images before this one. When I run this code, I don't get any error at all.

Answer (score 0):

this may or may not help.

To avoid using globla values to prevent images from being garbage collected you can use a modified Lable class.

```py
class imageLabel(ttk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.image_path = kwargs.pop('image', None)
        if self.image_path and os.path.isfile(self.image_path):
            self.image = Image.open(self.image_path)
            kwargs['image'] = self.imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        super(imageLabel, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)
    def destroy(self):
        super().destroy()
        self.__del__()
    def __del__(self):
        attrs = list(self.__dict__.keys())
        for attr in attrs:
            try:
                delattr(self, attr)
            except: pass
        del self
```

the **del** method clears all attributes from memory which delets the image from the memory of the application (basic garbage colletction). Probably not needed as that is usually handeled by python automatically.

this reaplces code in your `load_splash_image` to:

```
def load_splash_image():
    # Create a label to display the splash image
    splash_label = imageLabel(root, image=os.path.join(current_directory, "splash.png"))
    
    # Center the splash label on the root window
    splash_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
    
    # Start a timer to hide the splash screen after 3 seconds
    timer = root.after(3000, lambda: splash_label.destroy())
```

You can then use this class multiple times when you want an image to be loaded.
Simply pass the absolute path of the image as the image keyword: `image=c:\myproject\splash.png`.
Then when the

Comment: `del` doesn't clears anything from memory, at best `del` leads to garbage collection.

Comment: @Thingamabobs to be clear i was refereing to `\_\_del\_\_` method which is there to delete the attributes ready for garbage collection which should run instantly once the reference count reaches 0. As this was Tk code there was no real way of ensuring the correct deletion of modified wigets in whatever task is performed with this code so i included it as a 'just in case' as a basic override of the standard `destroy()` method.